# Downloading XML file through Java gives me a JSON file

Tags: java, xml, json

I've been trying to download the following XML file from this link through Java :

https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=bj6f8z64bnmn35hczeasbuut&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccity%3ESeattle%3C%2Fcity%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CstateProvinceCode%3EWA%3C%2FstateProvinceCode%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CcountryCode%3EUS%3C%2FcountryCode%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CarrivalDate%3E11%2F22%2F2014%3C%2FarrivalDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CdepartureDate%3E11%2F24%2F2014%3C%2FdepartureDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRoomGroup%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoom%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C%2FnumberOfAdults%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoom%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoomGroup%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CnumberOfResults%3E25%3C%2FnumberOfResults%3E%0A%3C%2FHotelListRequest%3E

But the thing is that I am getting a JSON file instead of the XML file when I use java codes (built in or external) to download the file, although I can normally download it from Chrome as a XML.

Code i am using :

```
URL url= new URL("https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=bj6f8z64bnmn35hczeasbuut&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccity%3ESeattle%3C%2Fcity%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CstateProvinceCode%3EWA%3C%2FstateProvinceCode%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CcountryCode%3EUS%3C%2FcountryCode%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CarrivalDate%3E11%2F22%2F2014%3C%2FarrivalDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CdepartureDate%3E11%2F24%2F2014%3C%2FdepartureDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRoomGroup%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoom%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C%2FnumberOfAdults%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoom%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoomGroup%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CnumberOfResults%3E25%3C%2FnumberOfResults%3E%0A%3C%2FHotelListRequest%3E") ;


      File sa= new File("C:\\Users\\Ramcos\\Desktop\\akaletc.xml");
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, sa);
```

Comment: Some actual, example Java code you've tried would help folks help you.

Comment: i am not sure about that particular api but I always cringe when i see api keys in posts, maybe edit?

Comment: File sa= new File("C:\\Users\\Ramcos\\Desktop\\akaletc.xml");
  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, sa);

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the "accept" http header to "application/xml". Probably that the server defaults it to json, but your browser defaults it to xml.

Comment: confirmed, both `Accept` and `Content-Type` with `application/json` give me a json response.

Comment: Well you send an http request to get the http response and its content? You need to modify your http request and add the accept header to it.

Comment: It's not working with me , could someone write it down?

Comment: @Rs123 edit your post and show us the code you are using to send the request. Then someone can give you specifics of how to set the header for the request.

Comment: @Rs123 no problem, i posted an answer to help you with the code but this answer should be the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

In android we use something like:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(method);

/* headers */
httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

The server tailors its response to what's in your `Accept` HTTP header. If you don't say your client accepts XML, the server falls back to JSOIN

If you set the Accept header to `application/xml` the server will return XML. For instance if you're using cURL:

```
curl -s -H 'Accept: application/xml' <URL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `URLConnection` object which you can get from your `URL` object. Then you can use the `setRequestProperty(String, String)` method to set a header. It should look something like this.

```
URL url = new URL("that url");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
connection.connect();
File sa = new File("C:\\Users\\Ramcos\\Desktop\\akaletc.xml");
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(connection.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(sa));
```